# Modern Authentication with IMAP to Outlook365

Tags: authentication, outlook, office365, jakarta-mail, imap

What is the recommended way of machine-to-machine communication that does not require user authorization for an IMAP client to Outlook365?  Authorization code flow does not appear to be intended for machine-to-machine type access.
The confidential client code flow does not seem to be implemented for IMAP.

Comment: There might not be one.  IMAP is basically an afterthought they implemented for the few people who really want to use an alternative MUA.  This stuff is unfortunately severely underdocumented, and if you’re making a microsoft specific solution, they would really prefer you to use modern APIs (eg, the HTTP Mail API), though I can’t guarantee you’ll have better luck authorizing for that.

Comment: This is the only thing I can find with reference to Client Credential Flow for IMAP(using a confidential application).  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=70577.  It would appear that their original Dec, 2021 timeframe for GA has been pushed to June.  So, RESTful API appears to have supplanted it?  Since you are probably correct, is there a non-interactive way of accessing RESTful API that you're aware of?